# Por que me cambia el orden del JSON con JAXB?

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jaxb

Estoy Desarrollando una API Rest con Jersey y
Estoy utilizando JAXB y con la anotación   @XmlRootElement

```html
@XmlRootElement
public class Car {
 private int idCar;
 private String model;
 private String color;
 
 public Car() {
  
 }
 
 public Car(String model, String color) {
  setModel(model);
  setColor(color);
 }
 
 public void setIdCar(int idCar) {
  this.idCar = idCar;
 }
 
 public int getIdCar() {
  return idCar;
 }
 
 public void setModel(String model) {
  this.model = model;
 }
 
 public String getModel() {
  return model;
 }
 
 public void setColor(String color) {
  this.color = color;
 }
 
 public String getColor() {
  return color;
 }
 
 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "Car [model=" + model + ", color=" + color + "]";
 }
 
}
```

Estoy convirtiendo una Clase Car a JSON con Jersey para que lo Regrese al solicitar el recurso

```html
@GET
 @Path("/{num : \\d+}")//digit only
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public Car getCar(@PathParam("num") int id) {
  Car objCar = ConnectionDB.getCarDB(id);
  return objCar;
 }
```

Pero al hacer el Get Me cambia el Orden del JSON 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
como es que funciona el mapeo de jaxb para que quede asi?

Comment: Supongo que es por el orden alfabético, pero la cuestión es que como accedes a los elementos por nombre pues la verdad da absolutamente lo mismo. Y además ¿qué orden esperas? ¿Según aparecen en tu código fuente?

Comment: El objeto json no es una lista ordenada, es un objeto compuesto de atributos y no debería haber ningún motivo valedero para que quisieras recibirlos ordenados.

Comment: Okay esta bien, muchas gracias @SJuan76 otro Juan tambien

Comment: otra cosa porque me respondieron como comentario y no como Respuesta, así no lo puedo calificarlas @Juan

Comment: Porque no hemos respondido tu pregunta. Una respuesta sería algo así como "la especificación X434kj43 establece que el orden será siempre alfabético" o "lo puedes especificar haciendo esto". Nosotros solo hemos cuestionado si realmente interesa preocuparse por el orden.

Comment: aaaa okay pero para mi ya responde mi duda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la respuesta simple es debido a que estás usando el esquema por defecto.

Como podrás ver en este diagrama arquitectural

[image: Diagrama de arquitectura JAXB]

tanto para serialización como para des-serialización se usa un esquema, y como tal vez hayas observado en JAXB se usan en concreto dos esquemas por defecto:

```
<xml ... xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ...>
```

Los detalles sobre el esquema base de XML lo puedes hallar en https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema

y el de JAXB en http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/jaxb/index.html.

Desde Java 6 la especificación JAXB provee por defecto la modalidad de [propiedades sin órden](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessorOrder.html#value%28%29).

Sin embargo puedes especificar tú el órden que deseas mediante la anotación

```
@XmlType (propOrder={"idCar","model","color"})
```

puesta a nivel de clase.

Si estás usando la implementación de la especificación JAXB llamada "Eclipselink Moxy" puedes agregar la anotación a nivel de clase:

```
@XmlAccessorOrder(XmlAccessOrder.ALPHABETICAL)
```

para garantizar que las propiedades se impriman siempre en órden alfabético al ser serializadas.

Es importante hacer notar que en versiones recientes de Java (creo desde la 11), JAXB ya no forma parte de Java SE y lo más recomendable es decargar JAXB como dependencia en aras de la portabilidad.